# Is $_SERVER information sensitive?

Tags: php, security, session

I am writing a bug submission class in my php application.  I want to capture the entire `$_SERVER` at the time an exception is thrown and if the user decides to submit a bug report, store the `$_SERVER` array in the database with other useful information like a description of problem, time, etc.

I plan on passing the captured `$_SERVER` to the bug report form in a `$_SESSION` but I am worried that if I do this I am exposing data that could be used to exploit my system. To name a couple:

- `SERVER_SOFTWARE`
- `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Am I putting myself at risk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point in such a class.
WHY user intervention, if your code can store all the relevant info automatically, safe and exact?

Why can't you just log all the relevant info in the exception handler at the time an exception is thrown?

To answer your question literally - yes, some of the server information considered sensitive.
though I see no way to expose it, unless your idea of bug report is to ask a user to send the report text via their own email.

Comment: I don't know he may send it to the client for some reason.

Comment: What if a bug doesn't get addressed until a month after it is reported and the log file has been cleared because of size/expiration?  That is why I was looking to store relevant information in a place more permanent than the log file. Also I was going to make a nifty bug tracker UI for the customer.

Comment: @TimeTravelMishap why not create a log function that if greater than x size rename log file and create a new log

Answer (score -1):

The class is not required.

Instead use this template for your scripts:

```
try {
    // You usual script here - but do not use die - use throw new Exception(...)
    // Could use include directive for example

    // Of course you may need to re-throw some exceptions

} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Here you can record the fault (i.e. details of the exception $e,
    // server variables $_SERVER, S_SESSION and the like

    // Now give the user the internal server error and a pretty message saying
    // something along the lines that you are sorry and it is not their fault.
}
```

This template will not expose any of the internal workings of your site to the remote client - no security implications.

Comment: exception handler have to be used for this.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - The code makes all exceptions caught - eventually. You could modify it (which I have done in the past) to catch particular exceptions and as well as logging the bug take other action (e.g. if unable to connect to the database email somebody)